# Saving .h and .cpp in different folders in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-c++

I was wondering if it were possible to change the default save locations for header and source files when writing C++ in Visual studio.

I have two folders `src` and `lib` in my project directory and what I want to do is whenever I add header files via the solution explorer could I change the file destination to the `lib` folder instead of defaulting to the root directory and having to manually use the file explorer.

This also applies to the other folder too.

Comment: Yes; just manually add the files from that folder to the solution

Comment: Header files are normally placed in an `inc` or `include` directory...

Answer (score 3):

As **@Ramhound** and **@DavidPostil**l already mentioned in comments, you can do it.
Please take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878703/keep-source-files-in-an-external-directory-in-visual-studio-c):

> You can put the .cpp and .h files wherever you want. A project file
>   just lists the locations of the source files. Create the .cpp and .h
>   files where you want them, perhaps with Notepad, and then use "Add
>   Existing File" to add them to the project. (Right-click on the project
>   name in Solution Explorer and choose "Add Existing File".)

Answer (score 0):

lib files are normally library files which are output of the build (the linker) so I do not understand how that is relevant so I will ignore that, I apologize if I misunderstand. I think however that you don't want to put header files in the lib directory, you should use another directory, as DavidPostill said.

I am still using VS 2013 but I assume VS 2015 is the same. In the project properties, the C/C++ General settings, is "Additional Include Directories". Perhaps that is what you are looking for.